# Find replace html using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, find

I've read a bunch of different posts and I can't figure out why this isn't working for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure it's something simple.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/®/g,"<sup>®</sup>"));
    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div>HelloWorld®</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you want to achive ?

Comment: You are using jQuery-isms (such as `$()`) but don't appear to have jQuery loaded by your page in a `<script>` tag..

Comment: Don't update your question when it's solved, use the green checkmark next to the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: That's my fault, sorry new to this.  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must wait after page ready so add your function inside `$(document).ready(function(){....})` or move your `<script>...</script>` tag as last element inside `<body>...</body>`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div>HelloWorld®</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/®/g,"<sup>®</sup>"));
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/®/g,"<sup>®</sup>"));
    });

});
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div>HelloWorld®</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't put a `<script>` tag there. That's invalid HTML. It needs to be inside the `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I've never seen a <script> tag or any other tag in that matter be used outside of the <html> tags.  I added the jQuery link inside the <head> tags but it's still not working.

Comment: run snippet it works result is `HelloWorld<sup>®</sup>`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it works for me. I output to the console the contents of the element before and after modifying them:

```
$("body").children().each(function() {

    console.log($(this).html());
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/®/g,"<sup>®</sup>"));
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

And the result is:

```
HelloWorld®
HelloWorld<sup>®</sup>
```

Check it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/m6kLgpj7/

Are you getting a different result? What is the problem you are observing?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I would probably just target the element by giving it a unique ID rather than iterate over every element in the body. However since that is the approach you asked about, this is how I would do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").children().each(function(idx, elem) {
    var newHtml = $(elem).html().replace(/®/g, "<sup>®</sup>");
    $(elem).html(newHtml);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<body>
  <div>HelloWorld®</div>
</body>
```

I think it's more clear when you use the second parameter that the jQuery each method provides (the element), rather than using 'this' all over the place....just my personal preference.

Also, take note of the document ready method i placed the rest of the script in to ensure. This ensures the script does not manipulate the DOM until the DOM is ready.